# mix-blend-mode on mobile in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

> I am running Android 10 and Chrome Beta 84.0.4147.89

But the rendering in Chrome and FF of mix-blend-mode seems to be very different. The background of the chat window should be white. When instead it is colorful.

1. So my question is how can this be fixed for Chrome browser on the
   mobile phone?
2. Also in Chrome on desktop version it seems to run fine as long as
   html becomes scrollable.

I am really confused as to what is happening and which fix may be applied to fix at least some of it.

> https://jsfiddle.net/f7xbnozt

```css
.chat-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.chat-container:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 95, 255) 0%, rgb(146, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 46, 25) 100%);
  content: '';
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chat div {
  color: white;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.chat .q {
  background: blue;
  margin: 6px 0 6px 50px;
}

.chat .a {
  background: green;
  margin: 6px 50px 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="q">Chat message...</div>
    <div class="q">Chat message...</div>
    <div class="a">Chat message...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing works is the algorithm.

Transparent background + blue and green + gradient background equals [vivid result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBMX0.png) you see in chrome.

While **white background** + blue and green + gradient background equals [the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2CBG.png).

```
.chat-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  ...
}
```

Curiously, if you copy the original code from jsfiddle to codepen, then nothing will work there either, even in firefox.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that was a very simple fix!
I guess I gave up too early on finding a solution.
That fixed all the issues.

Comment: Yeah I was kind of surprised too that many other CSS testing sites didn't support mix-blend-mode and simply didn't recognize it. :D

Comment: @VadimCool You are welcome. It will be nice of you to upvote the answer. I'm interested in getting the CSS badge and trying to keep a positive score — 4 responses = 4 upvotes.  :)

Comment: Although there is an issue with the dark background.... :/ mix-blend-mode has different options, but they all seem to ruin the colorful background....

Comment: mix-blend-mode sure has issues here and there and is hard to control. I've decided to go old school. We already have the tools to make something similar without using mix-blend-mode.